# Coherence*web vs WebLogic 'replicate-if-clustered'

Tags: java, session, weblogic, weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

1. What are the advantages of Coherence*web compared to WebLogic's 'replicate-if-clustered' session persistence? The only advantage I can see is that the heap is not cluttered with session data with Coherence*web. Please share any other advantages (or disadvantages) if exists?
2. If WebLogic's 'replicate-if-clustered' session persistence is used, will it copy session data into all other managed servers in the cluster? However I read that it will copy session data to a secondary managed server, not to all the managed servers in the cluster. When I tested I can see that with this ('replicate-if-clustered') I can access session data from any of the managed servers in the cluster.

Comment: If you use session replication within a weblogic cluster, each session is only replicated to ONE backup server, to limit network traffic If you need to access a session from any server in the cluster you can use : Coherence Web, File System Session Replication or JDBC Session replication.

Comment: That's what I read on several blogs. But When I tested session replication with 3 managed servers, I could access the session attribute with all the managed servers

Comment: Are you using Coherence*web to store your session ?

Comment: Yes -as with weblogic.xml's <wls:persistent-store-type>coherence-web</wls:persistent-store-type>

Comment: With this configuration your session is reachable from all servers. If you just use standard weblogic session replication your session is replicated in only one backup server.

Comment: When I tested I can see that with this ('replicate-if-clustered' - standard weblogic one) I can access session data from any of the managed servers in the cluster.

Comment: As you are setting <wls:persistent-store-type>coherence-web</wls:persistent-sto‌​re-type> you are out of the ootb configuration.

Comment: I have two questions posted - that I have tried both coherence-web and replicate session persistence. When I tested I can see that with 'replicate-if-clustered' I can access session data from any of the managed servers in the cluster.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin With replicate-session-in-a-cluster scenario, can backup server be selected by a user? IOW, if there are three managed servers - MS1, MS2 and MS3 and say MS3 machine is powerful than others, can MS3 machine be selected as backup for MS1 and MS2 machines?

Comment: @mnmopazem yes possible on your topology configs.

Comment: @FahimFarook Thanks for pitching in. Where can I accomplish that task in admin console? I tried to figure it but, I suppose I'm not looking at right place. Please help.